# Input text is not displayed properly when being grouped and using float text

Tags: angular, primeng

[image: Textbox not displayed properly]I'm trying to create a component with a group of Input text boxes which have a float label. But, when I group them the input text box is being cut off.
Below is the code which I'm using:

```
<p-fieldset legend="Search" [toggleable]="true" [collapsed]="false">
  <div class="ui-g ui-fluid">
    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
      <div class="ui-inputgroup">
        <span class="ui-float-label">
          <input id="float-input" type="text" size="25" pInputText />
          <label for="float-input">Proposal Id</label>
        </span>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
      <div class="ui-inputgroup">
        <span class="ui-float-label">
          <input id="float-input1" type="text" size="25" pInputText />
          <label for="float-input1">DCN</label>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
      <div class="ui-inputgroup">
        <span class="ui-float-label">
          <input id="float-input2" type="text" size="25" pInputText />
          <label for="float-input2">Customer Name</label>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
      <div class="ui-inputgroup">
        <span class="ui-float-label">
          <input id="float-input3" type="text" size="25" pInputText />
          <label for="float-input3">First Name</label>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
      <div class="ui-inputgroup">
        <span class="ui-float-label">
          <input id="float-input4" type="text" size="25" pInputText />
          <label for="float-input4">Last Name</label>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
      <div class="ui-inputgroup">
          <button pButton type="button" label="Clear" class="ui-button-secondary" (click)="clear()"></button>
          <span class="ui-float-label">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
          <button pButton type="button" label="Find"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</p-fieldset>
```

But, when I just use the float label without the grouping the text box is displayed properly without being cut-off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your  `<div class="ui-inputgroup">`, replace it with

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
```

there is a fixed template:

```
<p-fieldset legend="Search" [toggleable]="true" [collapsed]="false">
        <div class="ui-g ui-fluid">
          <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <span class="ui-float-label">
                <input id="float-input" type="text" size="25" pInputText />
                <label for="float-input">Proposal Id</label>
              </span>
             </div>
          </div>

          <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <span class="ui-float-label">
                <input id="float-input1" type="text" size="25" pInputText />
                <label for="float-input1">DCN</label>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <span class="ui-float-label">
                <input id="float-input2" type="text" size="25" pInputText />
                <label for="float-input2">Customer Name</label>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <span class="ui-float-label">
                <input id="float-input3" type="text" size="25" pInputText />
                <label for="float-input3">First Name</label>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <span class="ui-float-label">
                <input id="float-input4" type="text" size="25" pInputText />
                <label for="float-input4">Last Name</label>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                <button pButton type="button" label="Clear" class="ui-button-secondary" (click)="clear()"></button>
                <span class="ui-float-label">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                <button pButton type="button" label="Find"></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </p-fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is working. Thanks!!
But, since I'm not using bootstrap, but primeng styling, I used the class as "ui-sm-9".